# Unexpected -1 on my reputation for a question I did not interact with

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed on my reputation there is a -1 for a question I did not interact with: [image: From my reputation tab]

Here is the question: [Angular 4 : Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557390/angular-4-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error/49203794#49203794)

Again I did not interact with this question so why am I getting a -1 on my reputation for it?

Answer (score 9):

**Downvoting an answer costs you 1 point of your reputation.**

You haven't been downvoted, actually this happened because **you** downvoted an answer on this question.

Comment: hmm I don't think I downvoted it, at least I certainly didn't mean to. I don't even remember looking at it. in any case it will not let me undo that vote is it possible?

Comment: @BryanDellinger You can only undo your vote if the answer gets an edit. Which I just did to fix spelling and formatting. So now you should be able to undo your vote.

Comment: @BryanDellinger do you use a touchpad? I manage to do accidental "drive by voting" a little too often that way :/